# Dagger 2 injection not work with @ContributesAndroidInjector

Tags: android, dagger

I have this module for my activities bindings:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [BaseActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun bindsActivity(): BaseActivity

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

**BaseActivityModule**

```
@Module
abstract class BaseActivityModule {

    @Binds
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun provideProgressDialogManager(manager: ProgressDialogManager): ProgressManager

}
```

**ProgressDialogManager**

```
class ProgressDialogManager : ProgressManager {

    private var activity: Activity;
    private var instance: AtomicReference<ProgressDialog> = AtomicReference<ProgressDialog>();

    @Inject
    constructor(activity: BaseActivity){
        this.activity = activity as Activity
        this.instance.set(getDialog())
    }
```

My component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class, ApplicationServiceModule::class, HTTPClientModule::class, ServicesModule::class])
public interface AceleraApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    fun inject(app: AceleraApplication)
    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): AceleraApplicationComponent

    }

}
```

but if i do this:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), SalesforceActivityInterface, BaseView {

    private var logger: Logger = br.com.rede.acelera.util.Logger.create(javaClass)
    private var sf: SalesforceActivityDelegate = SalesforceActivityDelegate(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var progress: ProgressManager

}
```

i have this build error:

> e:
>   /Users/rafael-iteris/Documents/afvc/acelera/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/devProdDebug/br/com/rede/acelera/component/AceleraApplicationComponent.java:6:
>   error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
>   br.com.rede.acelera.util.ProgressManager cannot be provided without an
>   @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method. e:
>
> e: public abstract interface AceleraApplicationComponent extends
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector { e: 
>   ^ e:       br.com.rede.acelera.util.ProgressManager is injected at e: 
>   br.com.rede.acelera.base.BaseActivity.progress e:
>   br.com.rede.acelera.activity.main.MainActivity is injected at e:
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0) e:   A binding with
>   matching key exists in component:
>   br.com.rede.acelera.module.ActivityBuilder_BindsActivity.BaseActivitySubcomponent
>   e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while
>   annotation processing

any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Dagger starts injecting dependencies from subclasses, even if your `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` is in your base class (or you extend from `DaggerAppCompatActivity`).

Then it looks for subclass definitions in your `ActivityBuilder`.

So, to inject into an abstract base class, you need to provide that dependency (via Module in `ActivityBuilder`) in every subclass of it.

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class, BaseActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this BaseActivityModule, and remove the @Inject annotation from the ProgressDialogManager constructor.

```
@Module
class BaseActivityModule {

    @Provide
    @ActivityScope
    fun provideProgressDialogManager(activity: BaseActivity): ProgressManager {
       return ProgressDialogManager(activity)
    }
}
```